# Show data based on selected date - QlikView

Tags: date, datetime, qlikview, qliksense

I have a list box of dates and a table which has datetime as dimension. The dates from list box is a separate table from that with complete date. I tried connecting them by cutting the datetime into just date (another field) in my select script but did not work. So I thought this should be done on the conditional of datetime dimension but I'm not sure how to do this. How should I be able to show data based on selected dates in Filters?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how you are "cutting the datetime into date"? Using the floor function or the Date/Date# functions?

Comment: @BrunoMarques Yes, my mistake this was in load script, not in SQL select. What it did was it only selected a particular datetime which is the same row as this date. For ex. if I select 2017-10-20 from the list, it will only select one row e.g. 2017-10-20 3:38:44 PM. Also, a bunch of duplicate dates on the list, which became like an ID for each datetime.

Comment: @BrunoMarques Is there a way to do this by conditional dimension, not in script? I tried adding this in condition, `if(Date([DateTime], 'YYYY-MM-DD') = [Date], [DateTime])` but nothing changed on the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend two different approaches, recomending the first one :

- On the LOAD script, along side loading the DateTime field, loading the same field again with only the Date part and use than one for filtering. Something like :

  ```
  LOAD
  <... some fields ...>
  DateTimeField,
  Date(Floor(DateTimeField)) as DateTimeFieldFilter
  <... some more fields...>
  ```
- Add a field selector for you DateTime field, then to Properties, Field dropdown and choose the last option "Expression". On the Expression box enter Date(Floor(DateTimeField)).